# Pass function props in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning how to use react-ketting

There are some examples of using it on the [wiki](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting/wiki/React)

And in `UseCollection` section I am stuck

Could someone explain what is this and how it works:

```
function MyCollectionItem({resource}: { resource: Resource<Article> }) {
```

Full snippet is:

```
function MyCollection() {

  const {
    loading,
    error,
    items
  } = useCollection<Article>('/articles');

  if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div class="error">boo</div>;

  return <ul>{items.map(item => <MyCollectionItem resource={item} />)}</ul>

}

function MyCollectionItem({resource}: { resource: Resource<Article> }) {
  const {
    loading,
    error,
    data
  } = useResource(resource);

  if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div className="error">boo</div>;

  return <li>{data.title} - {data.body}</li>;
}
```

I want to add string prop to `MyCollectionItem` like

```
function MyCollectionItem({resource}: { resource: Resource<Article> }, anotherOption: string) {
```

And call it

```
<MyCollectionItem·resource={item}·anotherOption='project'·key={item.uri}·/>
```

Got error

```
[tsserver 2322] [E] Type '{ resource: Resource<Article>; anotherOption: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { resource: Resource<Article>; }'. Property 'anotherOption' does not exist on type 
 IntrinsicAttributes & {  resource: Resource<Article>; }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By React covention, all component props are passed as an object as the 1st argument of your Functional Component.

So if you call the component:

```
<MyCollectionItem
  resource={item}
  anotherOption='project'
/>
```

React will actually call the function like:

```
MyCollectionItem({
  resource: item,
  anotherOption: "project"
})
```

Therefore your extra prop should be an extra member of the 1st argument (usually through destructuring),  instead of a 2nd positional argument:

```
function MyCollectionItem({
  resource,
  anotherOption
}: {
  resource: Resource<Article>;
  anotherOption: string;
}) {}
```